# How to access system logs

Tags: command-line, logging

I need to find large amounts of text to provide data for a ML model (essentially for testing). I thought accessing various system logs could be interesting.

So far I have tried playing around `netstat`, but there is not quite enough data there. How can I access larger system logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Ubuntu, try

```
gunzip -c /var/log/*.gz
```

That unzips all your log archives to stdout. Likely doable on all distros with some minorr changes.